# Linker errors when building OpenCV3 using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.0

I would like to build `Opencv 3` using `Visual Studio 2015`.
So, I've downloaded `Opencv 3` from the `Github` repository, extracted it to `C:\opencv` and used `Cmake` to generate the `Visual Studio project` to be built.

After that, I tryied to build the generated `Visual studio solution project` (`ALL_BUILD` project inside `OpenCV.sln`), but I got many errors related to the linking:

```
55>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_highgui300d.lib'  
========== Build: 11 succeeded, 47 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is it necessary to link libraries even during the build (but `dll's` aren't generated yet)? or is there something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `OpenCV 3` is still not very stable.
I managed to compile the last `OpenCV 2.4` version using `Visual Studio 2015 (v14) 64bits`.